# Prevent updating mysql data if is not received from the form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form to update the user data in my database. I am posting the data to another page to update my database. However if I go to directly the page directly (ex: update2.php?userid=30), database is being updated with empty data.

here is what I have inside my update2.php file

```
$userid=$_GET["userid"];

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

include("connect.php");

$updateuser=mysql_query("update users username='$username', email='$email', phone='$phone', where ID=$userid");

if($updateuser){
echo "Done";
}

else{
echo "Failed";
}
```

Comment: Well then, add some validity checking. `if (!isset($_POST['username']))`...

Comment: Should I validate username or userid?

Comment: You should check for request method and validate all the data. A mandatory reminder: sql injections

Comment: Validate all the data. Anyone can send anything at any time to you. If you don't want to insert invalid data into your database, you need to validate any and all incoming data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because when you go to the page directly, you are making a "GET" action, not a "POST". When you send the information via form you can choose if you want to send via "POST" (e.g.: `<form action="action_page.php" method="POST">`) or "GET" (e.g.: `<form action="action_page.php" method="GET">`). The GET method puts the variables in the URL (e.g: "update2.php?userid=30&phone=12345"), while POST doesn't.

A solution is not to be so specific and use **$_REQUEST** instead of `$_POST` or `$_GET`. $_REQUEST reads both from $_POST and $_GET:

```
$userid=$_REQUEST["userid"];

$username = $_REQUEST["username"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["phone"];
```

***PS:*** I'm assuming that your code is not accessible from the outside world and/or its not an important database and/or you oversimplified the code for understanding purposes. I say that because, it is very vulnerable to SQL injection. What if I access `update2.php?userid=1 OR 1=1` or worse `update2.php?userid=1;DROP TABLE an_important_table`

**UPDATE:**

I think that I misunderstood the question. I thought that you want to update the database when accessing directly, but the data was being updated with empty values. Now I understand that you won't let anyone to update directly.

So, check if you are getting the response by POST (form) or GET (directly via browser). You can check if your `$_POST["userid"]` is setted for that or use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") { // OR if isset($_POST["userid"])
  echo "You can't access this directly!";
}
else {
$userid=$_GET["userid"];

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

include("connect.php");

$updateuser=mysql_query("update users username='$username', email='$email', phone='$phone', where ID=$userid");

if($updateuser){
echo "Dode";
}

else{
echo "Failed";
}
}
```

Comment: database is still being updated when I visit update2.php?userid=30&phone=12345 page directly. Should I use POST method instead off GET ?

Comment: Your initial paragraph is very wrong. PHP's `_GET` and `_POST` variables do not really correspond to the request type. `_GET` contains all parameters from the URL's *query string*, `_POST` contains the decoded *request body*. Nothing more, nothing less. You can POST to `foo.php?id=42` with additional body data just fine, and the OP's code will work just fine. In fact, that's a decent RESTful schema to use, really.

Comment: @deceze !? I never stated that $_GET and $_POST corresponds to the requested type. Notice that I typed `GET` to refer to a request type and `$_GET` to refer the variable. The uppercase is to getting attention to the type, not a variable reference.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I may have been misconstruing what you were trying to say there. My bad!

Comment: I understand, I do the same in this question. Notice that my answer to OP was completely different of what he explicitly asks in the title. I had to write an update that begins with "I think that I misunderstood the question". :P

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone'])) {

  $userid=$_GET["userid"];
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $phone = $_POST["phone"];

  include("connect.php");

  $updateuser=mysql_query("update users username='$username', email='$email', phone='$phone', where ID=$userid");

  if($updateuser){
    echo "Done";
  }

  else{
    echo "Failed";
  }

}
else {
  echo "Please use the form";
}
```

Comment: BTW, `isset` accepts multiple parameters: `isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], ..)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can always add a hidden field in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="UPDATE" />
```

and then validate it before making any updates

```
if ($_POST["action"] == "UPDATE") { 
     //update script
}
```